# A new connection was rejected because the maximum number of connections has been reached

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I wrote a code in C# that get data from local database, manipulate and then sync it with a third party.

I open connection in start of my application and then close it when all of my calls are ended(as I need an Open connection in my loop). I am using datareaders and datatable and properly disposing these after use.

```
using (DataTable dataTableLocation = new DataTable()) //this is inside a loop
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryLocation, conn))
    {
       cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

       // Use the above SqlCommand object to create a SqlDataReader object.
       using (SqlDataReader queryCommandReader3 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
            // Use the DataTable.Load(SqlDataReader) function to put the results of the query into a DataTable.
            dataTableLocation.Load(queryCommandReader3);
       }

    }
    //Data manipulation and then sync
}
```

I have set Max Pool Size to 800. After 4 hours my console app get crashed and when I looked in windows event, it says

> A new connection was rejected because the maximum number of connections on session ID 63 has been reached. Close an existing connection on this session and retry

While calls are made I constantly monitored database to see active connections, it shows 7-8

```
select * from sys.dm_os_performance_counters where counter_name ='User Connections'
```

Do I have to dispose,close connection and then recreate it again in a every loop?

Code for DB connection

```
string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString;
SqlConnection  conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Comment: Your question does not include the whole code. I don't see any code regarding the connections handling. Please include all the relevant code.

Comment: `I open connection in start of my application and then close it when all of my calls are ended`  Apparently not.  You would not run out of connections if you were using just one over and over

Comment: @yarimi I had updated question

Comment: @Plutonix Does it matter how long that connection remains open?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the code you _haven't_ shown. What happens in _"Data manipulation and then sync"_?

Comment: @NaeemShakir You are not closing the sql connection. just use Using statement for it

Comment: That DB connection snippet is worthless without some context

Comment: I close connection after the loop `conn.Close();`. The part I didn't showed is simply checking for value if they are null or not and then send it using RestSharp post call.

Comment: connection string is `Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=naeem;Max Pool Size=800;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=300`

Comment: Please don't include real credentials on this site, or any other site really.

Comment: @NaeemShakir, try removing MultipleActiveResultSets=True unless you are actually using MARS. The error message suggests you have 800 sessions on a single connection, most likely due to a bug.  Removing MARS will probably raise an exception where the problem is.